# how to pass context to cdk app during snapshot testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, jestjs, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to perform snapshot testing for my stack in cdk. This stack is passed some props which are acquired by context.

During actual deployment, I am able to access context because it does get passed to my stack **[ no problem over here ]**.

```
cdk deploy --all -c env=dev --require-approval never
```

During snapshot testing, I want to pass the same context for dev, stg and prod.

Right now I have hard coded the context values for snapshot testing. Is there any better way to achieve this. Right now I have hardcoded values for dev environement, is there a way to a achieve programatically for stg and prod like the same way we do during actual deployment.

```
test('Snapshot', () => {

    const app = new cdk.App({
        context: {
            env: "dev",
            key1: "value1",
            key2: "value2",
            key3: {
                subkey: "subvalue3",
            },
        }
    });
    const env = app.node.tryGetContext("env");

    if (!env)
        throw new Error(
            "Context variable missing on CDK command. Pass in as `-c env=XXX`"
        );
    const key3 = app.node.tryGetContext("key3");
    const key1: string = app.node.tryGetContext(
        "key1"
    );

    const key2: string = app.node.tryGetContext(
        "key2"
    );
    const key3: string = app.node.tryGetContext(
        "key3"
    );
   

    const stack = new my-stack(app, 'test-stack', {
        Env: env,
        Key1: key1,
        key2: key2,
        key3: key3,
    })
    const template = Template.fromStack(stack).toJSON();
    expect(template).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using python, but I'm sure you could use the same concept. I read in the cdk.json file and update it via code:

```
with open("cdk.json") as config:
    cdk_context = json.load(config)
    my_context = cdk_context['context']
    my_context.update({'lifecycle': 'dev'})
    print(my_context)

app = cdk.App(context=my_context)
```